# Pyramid override default requests log to add new parameters

Tags: python, logging, python-requests, pyramid

So I use Pyramid and I need to log all outgoing requests. I added this to `configuration.ini`:

```
[logger_requests]
level = DEBUG
handlers = console
qualname = urllib3
```

And this works fine.

```
1 2019-12-19T14:44:14.888+02:00 kazibo-msi APPNAME - DEBUG [urllib3.connectionpool][139843373852416 route="/status" x_request_id="9f7286e1-c6be-4136-83ba-2666fe1f854f"] https://website.com:443 "GET /rest/billing/debt/health HTTP/1.1" 200 1502
```

But I also need to log the time elapsed making request. Using `requests` package I can do it like that:

```
requests.get(url='https://somewebsite.com/data').elapsed
```

But how can I add this information to log now? I know about the option to add `logger.log(...)` but I would like to avoid it.

Comment: I found the spot where request is logged in urllib3. Seems like the only way to achieve my goal is to log data in the same file where the request is made, because logging in urllib3 looks like this:
        log.debug(
            '%s://%s:%s "%s %s %s" %s %s',
            self.scheme,
            self.host,
            self.port,
            method,
            url,
            http_version,
            httplib_response.status,
            httplib_response.length,
        )

Answer (score 0):

For code that I control I'd usually wrap things in my own utility that I can instrument instead of trying to patch/modify how urllib3 works or performs its own logging. This could be just a few functions you use across the codebase or a custom `requests.Session` subclass, etc.